# Set MeshGeometry Positions with one string in code behind

Tags: wpf

In XAML we can put one long string in the positions property, How do I do this in the code behind ?

XAML way:

```
<MeshGeometry3D x:Name="MeshGeometry3D"
                                Positions="
                                  -1,-1,-1   1,-1,-1   1,-1, 1  -1,-1, 1
                                  -1,-1, 1   1,-1, 1   1, 1, 1  -1, 1, 1
                                   1,-1, 1   1,-1,-1   1, 1,-1   1, 1, 1
                                   1, 1, 1   1, 1,-1  -1, 1,-1  -1, 1, 1
                                  -1,-1, 1  -1, 1, 1  -1, 1,-1  -1,-1,-1 
                                  -1,-1,-1  -1, 1,-1   1, 1,-1   1,-1,-1
                                  "
                              />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PointCollectionConverter pcc = new PointCollectionConverter();
var points = (PointCollection)pcc.ConvertFromString("-1,-1,-1   1,-1,-1   1,-1, 1  -1,-1, 1");
MeshGeometry3D mg = new MeshGeometry3D();
mg.Positions = points;
```